# error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am really confused on why I am getting following compilation error.
Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler.

`error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

class MyException {
public:
    MyException(    std::string message, 
                        int line = 0) : m_message(message),
                                        m_line(line) {}
    const char* what() const throw(){
        if ( m_line != 0 ) {
            std::ostringstream custom_message;
            custom_message << "Parsing Error occured at ";
            custom_message << m_line << " Line : ";
            custom_message << m_message;        
            m_message = custom_message.str();
        }
        return m_message.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string m_message;
    int m_line;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    try {
        // do something
    }catch(MyException &e){
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Error is coming at line
`m_message = custom_message.str();`

Comment: You're missing the header `<string>`, which might account for the behavior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You declare the method as const

```
const char* what() const throw(){
```

but then you try to change the object

```
m_message = custom_message.str();
```

so you get an error.

What you should do instead is construct the custom message in the constructor.

```
class MyException {
public:
    MyException(const std::string& message, int line = 0) : 
        m_message(message), m_line(line) {
        if ( m_line != 0 ) {
            std::ostringstream custom_message;
            custom_message << "Parsing Error occured at ";
            custom_message << m_line << " Line : ";
            custom_message << m_message;        
            m_message = custom_message.str();
        }
    }
    const char* what() const throw(){
        return m_message.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string m_message;
    int m_line;
};
```

Also I changed your code to pass the std::string by reference, which is usual practice.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign to `MyException::m_message` inside a const-qualified method `MyException::what()`. Inside such `what()` the entire `*this` object is considered to be `const`, which means that `m_message` member is also `const`. You can't assign anything to a const-qualified `std::string` object, since `std::string`'s assignment operator requires a modifiable (i.e. a non-const one) object on the left-hand side. You are supplying a `const` one.

If you really want to be able to modify the `m_message` inside `what()`, you should declare it as `mutable` member of the class (in this case it appears to be a good idea). Or use some other approach.

As @john noted, in your specific case it makes more sense to actually build `m_message` in constructor instead of postponing it till `what()`. I don't really understand why you'd even want to rebuild your `m_message` every time you call `what()`. Unless your `m_line` is expected to change somehow from one call to `what()` to another, there's really no need to do it every time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers;

You're not including the `<string>` header, which may be the cause of a problem later.

Something that used to get me a lot is that some `std::` headers include others, which allows you to use a class, but maybe only with limited functionality because the `std::` headers that they include are the **bare minimum** that is needed for that file to run. This is quite an annoyance because sometimes you declare a `std::` class such as `string` and you haven't included the header, the definition will be fine but everything else may or may not work - leading you to a lot of debugging because the definition worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

See the declaration of the `what()` function, it is marked `const` (the second `const` on the line). That means that it cannot alter any member variables, in your case the `m_message` string. That is why you get the error.

Now, how do you fix it?

Your code is wrong, your `what()` function will prepend the `"Parsing Error occured at "` etc. text each time you invoke the `what()` function. So, instead of doing that having to modify the `m_message` member, I suggest that you format the entire message in the ctor of the class:

```
MyException(std::string message, int line = 0)
{
    if (line != 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream custom_message;
        custom_message << "Parsing Error occured at ";
        custom_message << line << " Line : ";
        custom_message << message;        
        m_message = custom_message.str();            
    }
    else
        m_message = message;
}
```